# Git: Remove old mode 100644 new mode 100755 on previous commits

Tags: git, commit

I was working on my old Android phone's kernel. I imported the manufacturer's changes and splitted them into commits.
However, after I finished the process, I realized that there are a lot of files that are shown as edited, but is the only the permission that's edited.
On the git logs, as a result, it shows things like these:

```
diff --git a/include/linux/usb/audio.h b/include/linux/usb/audio.h
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

I searched the internet, and found out that I can solve this by doing

```
git config core.filemode false
```

However, this seems to change only for future commits.

How can I edit all my previous commits (almost as 70+ commits) and remove these files as recorded as being edited?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Old (existing) commits are set in stone.

In general you should never have to *change* `core.filemode` as Git should have set it correctly.  On any Windows system it would therefore already be set to `false` for you.  It looks like you, or at least someone, somehow managed to get a setup that was wrong, that produced these incorrect commits.

You *cannot* fix the incorrect commits, but if they bother you enough, you *can* make new, very-slightly-different commits.  These new, very-slightly-different commits should exactly match the old commits in all respects but one: the recorded file *modes* in the new commits will match the recorded file modes in their parent commits, so that there is no difference at all in the revised snapshots when each revised snapshot is compared to its parent snapshot.<sup>1</sup>

The downside to doing this work, as will be obvious from footnote 1, is that you have to revise many commits, and now you have a new and different repository with replacements for those 70+ old commits.  You must now get *everyone* who has a clone of this Git repository to switch to another new clone, in which the 70+ *new* (fixed) commits replace the 70 old (slightly incorrect) commits.

It's usually simpler—as well as quite harmless—just to live with the existing mistake.

---

<sup>1</sup>Remember that each Git commit contains a *full snapshot of every file*, including the file's mode.  The issue you have is that at some point, someone told Git—perhaps through this somehow-incorrect `core.filemode` setting—that all the *new* commits should record the files as mode `100755` (`rwxr-xr-x`) instead of mode `100644` (`rw-r--r--`).  The first commit that went from 100644 to 100755 produces the diff.  From then on, each *new* commit that says `100755` produces no diff, because the mode doesn't change.

As soon as you make *one* corrected commit in which the updated files are all `mode 100644`, though, that corrected commit compares nicely to its parent, but poorly to the *subsequent uncorrected* commit.  So you must now make *another* new commit, the same as the subsequent commit but with the modes corrected.  This repeats for *every* new commit.

The end result is that you must double up all 70+ commits: now you have 140+ commits.  Then you simply *stop using* the "wrong" ones, and use the "right" ones instead.

Comment: it sounds like they may not have committed them anywhere other than locally, and nobody else is using the commits, so they probably want to and would get benefit from regenerating their work!

Comment: @ti7: That's the one big exception to the "usually easier to just live with it" rule. Unfortunately there's no existing tool for doing this en-masse either. There's probably a way to rig up an appropriate `git filter-branch`, using the old filter-branch script.

Comment: Hello, first, it is right that nobody is actually using my works as it isn't on the internet now, only locally. (Do have a backup, though.) I do all my works in a Debian system, so the thing is that it seems like the manufacturer of the phone worked on the kernel on Windows systems too.

Comment: When I merge a newer CodeAurora tag on top of this kernel, I get more than 300 merge conflicts, many of them happening from files like these. The files have no edit in them, but the git history shows as if they are somehow edited as I said on the first post, and the conflicts happen in there. (Or maybe I understood wrong of how git mergetool works?)

Comment: File modes work correctly on Linux file systems (except if you mount a Windows file system that is), so when working on debian, you wouldn't normally have any `core.filemode` issues. But simply putting in a fixup commit (to change the modes of files) should get you past any *file-mode-related* merge issues (if that's a problem—it seems like it shouldn't be; Git should combine these just fine). What I'd expect to see as a problem is a case where someone did their work on Windows and put in CRLF line endings.

Comment: In any case, you're now talking about merging your work (your commits) with someone else's work/commits, which isn't what your original question was about.